# Turn off transitions \uncover \pause while keeping the TOC within the doc

Tags: beamer

I want to hand my students the slides without transitions while keeping the table of contents within the document. `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}` turns off transitions but it removes the TOC along the document.

Comment: Err. I don't think it does. I've made handouts with the contents and I never had to do anything special... Could you create a minimal example that shows the problem?

Comment: Let me see if I explain myself correctly. If I use "handout" option, transitions are turned off but only the "outline" slide at the beginning is left. All the others are gone. I have to understand that the compiler treats the "outline" slides as transitions. THank you for you comment by the way

Comment: Right. It turns off the _repeats_ of the ToC at the beginning of each section? Is that right?

Comment: Yes, it is right! I do not want that. A 30-40 slide presentation without breaks and without the outline in between is hard to follow. And I don't like the idea of putting the section/subsection on top of each slide. I have been googling for the remedy in the last hour. So far nothing. Thanks again

Comment: I found a solution, but I am trying to understand why it works. Will post it shortly

Comment: \AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer><handout>{Outline}
      \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 8):

(Adding answer-in-question as an answer)

Add `*` to the overlay options in here

```
\AtBeginSubsection[]  
  {  
    \begin{frame}<*>{Outline}  
      \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]  
    \end{frame}  
  }
```